# What is wrong with this relay circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, relay

I've recently designed a basic driving circuit for a 5V relay, but it appears to be malfunctioning since the output current remains at 0A, as if the coil isn't being energized. Can you help me identify the issue with this circuit?

I am utilizing an ESP8266 to control the relay, powered by an external 5V source. The relay is rated for up to 30VDC, making the 12V output suitable for this application.

V1 corresponds to one of the GPIO pins of the ESP8266. When V1 is set to 3.3V, it activates Q1, effectively grounding pin 2 of U1 instead of leaving it in a floating state. As a result, current can flow from the VCC source through the current-limiting resistor R2, pass through the LED, and continue from pin 1 of U2 to pin 2. The grounding of pin 2 is made possible by the activation of Q1.
Similarly, the same process occurs on the other side. When pin 2 is grounded, the opposite side of the optocoupler becomes conductive, and pin 3 of U1 establishes a connection to VCC. In this state, Q2 is activated, establishing a connection between node 8 and ground. This forms a new closed loop, redirecting the current through the D1 diode instead of passing it through the relay's coil. Consequently, the normally open (NO) pin is connected to the common (C) pin.

[image: Relay Circuit 1]
[image: Relay Circuit 2]

**Update 1:**

Replacing the LED
[image: Relay Circuit 3]

**Update 2:**
[image: Relay Circuit 4]

Comment: I’m not sure what the opto coupler is bringing to this circuit.

Comment: Presumably the shared ground for the left and right side of the optocoupler is only for simulation purposes?

Comment: @Bryan I'm attempting to isolate the MCU to protect it, a standard practice in relay modules. However, there's a challenge with the MCU being an ESP8266, which operates with 3.3V GPIOs, not 5V. To address this, I need to either connect pin 1 of U1 to 5V when the GPIO pin is high or connect pin 2 of U1 to ground when the GPIO is high to create a closed loop. I've opted for the second approach, which involves connecting pin 2 to ground.

Comment: @pipe, I've recently connected a different ground type to the emitter of Q2, and nothing has changed. However, I'd like to gain a better understanding of this. Is there any possibility that the MCU could be damaged due to having a common ground in the circuit?

Comment: Not related to why your circuit doesn't work, but switching transistor Q2 should have a base pulldown resistor e.g. 100k from node 7 to GND. Q1 doesn't need one as long as the ESP8266 is pulling low when off, which should be the default.

Comment: @M-125 I’ve had great success in similar circuits using a GPIO driven mosfet to directly energize the relay coil, and I suspect even your BJT q2 would suffice in this application. That is unless pipe is correct and the 5V supply must be fully isolated from the 3v3

Comment: _"attempting to isolate the MCU to protect it"_ Protect against what?

Comment: @elchambro, thank you for the suggestion. I've added a base pulldown resistor for Q2 as you mentioned.

Comment: @Bryan, I'm having trouble fully understanding your explanation. If you could provide a schematic, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @winny, I can't explain the function of the optocoupler and how it achieves isolation here (in comments), but you can find more details by searching online if you're interested.

Comment: Opposite, you explain your reasoning. Ideally with simulation results.

Answer (score 5):

There is a 5V drop across the LED and 0A of current through it. This indicates an open circuit somewhere between the probes PR4 and PR5. You should use a specific LED model, not a generic. Check that this branch is properly connected in the simulator.

[image]

Comment: I've replaced the LED with a new one. You can find the updated schematic image in the original question post above.

Answer (score 4):

Since your own green LED and the LED inside opto-isolator U1 are in series, the 5V supply is shared between them, and LED current is probably too low. You should place each LED (and its current limiting resistor) in parallel, to allow the full 5V to appear across each diode+resistor pair.

Secondly, relay coil current is surely many tens, or even hundreds, of milliamps. With a 10kΩ base resistor R3, you obtain a base current in Q2 of 0.4mA or so, which is probably barely sufficient to saturate Q2. 2.2kΩ is a better value for R3, to obtain closer to 2mA.

According to the [TLP521 datasheet](https://www.futurlec.com/Datasheet/LED/TLP521.pdf), CTR is 60%, so with 2mA of current through R3 and U1's transistor, you also require U1 LED current to be at least \$\frac{2mA}{60\%}=3.3mA\$.

Here a design which fixes all these issues:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSmupQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I've added R5, which is recommended to sink any opto-isolator leakage current, and keep Q2 off when it should be off.

The opto-isolator is completely redundant in this circuit. Both ground and positive supply are common to the microcontroller and relay sides, rendering any isolation between them pointless, and you don't need an opto-isolator. I am not referring to anything connected to the relay switch contacts, which is isolated anyway by the relay itself, I mean Q2 and the relay coil. If these elements are sharing the same ground or power supply as the microcontroller, then opto-isolation makes no sense.

If the systems on either side of the opto-isolator are indeed are independent, and have their own supplies, then correct use of an opto-isolator might look like the circuit below, in which you'll see the two halves of the circuit have absolutely no electrical connection between them:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f26HNo.png)</sup>

If the two sides are sharing grounds or supplies, the circuit cannot benefit from opto-isolation, and you would get identical results from this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f48ZLg.png)</sup>

In fact, if relay coil current is 100mA or less, and you don't require isolation, then even the following, much simpler circuit, would work:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0R9Bl.png)</sup>

Comment: "In fact, if relay coil current is 100mA or less, and you don't require isolation, then even the following, much simpler circuit, would work:", the simulation indicates a coil current exceeding 200 mA. The optocoupler issue is likely due to the shared supply line between the MCU and relay. I can't use separate power sources for MCU, circuit, and load. I rely on one external 5V source, which powers the ESP via a 5V to 3.3V regulator, and another one 12V, which powers the load.

Answer (score 3):

Your simulation does not make much sense. Perhaps the LED model is missing.

In a real circuit, it will probably work if the relay coil resistance (I don't see that on the simulation) is more than about 100Ω, but it would be better if the relay driver base resistor was lower- perhaps 1kΩ, allowing a relay current of 50 or 100mA.

You should put the LED and optoisolator LED in parallel rather than series (each with its own series resistor, of course), say 5mA each, and to reduce the LED driver base resistor to maybe 1kΩ as well. The series resistor for the optoisolator LED would be something like 680Ω for 5mA and (if the LED has a 2.8V Vf, say), about 360Ω.

Comment: It cannot be a good idea to use the series external LED under any circumstances. So I'd exclude that from the answer. Your advice about using a separate BJT seems the only appropriate option if the questioner wants an externally visible LED. The Toshiba datasheet gives somewhat conflicting suggestions, showing 10 mA under `electrical specifications` while perhaps still higher in their `recommended operating conditions`. But also showing 5 mA for their CTR (probably to get an optimal result.) They also show no guarantee at all for CTR on non-GB ranked parts when operating with saturated Vce!

Comment: @periblepsis Changed. It could be okay-ish with a red LED (Vf ~= 2V) and the IR LED (Vf ~= 1.2V) from a 5V supply but it's better to not do it.

Comment: When a resistor is used as a current limiter like this, the overhead voltage (resistor drop) has everything to do with its ability to regulate. If you leave it little voltage overhead, then it doesn't really regulate much. (I'm thinking here about temperature range of operation and part variations.) I think trying to operate at such thin margins, especially stacking two temperature-varying forward voltage LEDs in series, is just *wrong* and cannot be considered `managed`. (May look good on paper when using a narrow enough view but is wrong just the same.)

Comment: [Here is where I'd fall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RxWU.png). And even then I'd plan on expecting to see no better than about 20% CTR. (Note their Vce(sat) entry where they show both IF and IC. That's where I get 20%.)

Answer (score 0):

One issue is you have   LEDs in series, the combined voltage drop is approaching 5V, measure the current and make sure it's enough to activate the opto-led. If it isn't put the diodes in parallel  with equalising resistors, or look at reducing R1,R2  .

Comment: I've included another screenshot from the simulation, which indicates that there is no current flowing through these two LEDs. I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

Your measurements say no current flow through the photo does in your photo isolator, you need to investigate why. A suggestion above re diode voltage drops may be the answer, or some other issue. More measurements would help. To complete isolation of the micro i would drive the optoisolator diode from the 3.3 source, removing the vcc connection and then put the led in the opto transistor path.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested it , though I don't have an optocoupler on my simulator app so I just use transistors.

Here are my results

When turned on
[image: Relay-driver]

And when off
[image: Relay-driver-2]